# Query a table which select all dates in table which have same year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `tk`. It has a column `effective_date` with a data type of `date`. The table also has some other columns. What I want to do is query the table such that output contains all dates having same year but month should differ

I have tried with below query in SQL Server, but it's not returning the desired result:

```
select * tk_id
from tk
group by tk_id, YEAR(effective_date);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a `where` clause?

```
select *
from t
where effective_date >= '2019-01-01' and effective_date < '2020-01-01'
```

Comment: Actually in that table there are many records for a particular date,, what i am interested in are records which have same year but different month. But they should be grouped. For example:  2016-02-30, 2016-03-01, 2017-03-01,2017-04-01

Comment: @TusharLikhar . . . I think you should ask a new question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.